# questions about supers and subclasses

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance

I'm new to actionscript so please bear with me.

I just started working with supers and subclasses.

My question is basically this: Why is it that when I use the line
`scoreDisplay.text = currentValue.toString();`

it is run with the  line `reset();`

Why cant it be run with say current value = 0 instead?

here is the super

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class Counter extends MovieClip
{
    public var currentValue:Number;

    public function Counter()
    {
        reset();
    }

    public function addToValue( amountToAdd:Number ):void
    {
        currentValue = currentValue + amountToAdd;
        updateDisplay();
    }

    public function reset():void
    {
        currentValue = 0;
        updateDisplay();
    }

    public function updateDisplay():void
    {

    }
 }
}
```

and the subclass

```
import flash.text.TextField;
public class Score extends Counter
{
    public function Score()
    {
        super();
    }

    override public function updateDisplay():void
    {
        super.updateDisplay()
        scoreDisplay.text = currentValue.toString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by _use the line_ or _run with the line_? Clarify your question.

Comment: i meant why is it that i have to put reset(); in the Counter class's constructor. Why can't i just put currentValue=0 in the constructor instead. (otherwise the score in the game wont be at 0). hope that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, if you only put `currentValue = 0;` in your Counter class' constructor, then you don't update the display list. Your `reset` function however does call the `updateDisplay` function. So if you call `super();` from a subclass which overrides the `updateDisplay` function, then the super class will call the `reset` which will call the `updateDisplay` OF your subclass.
Also, in your current example, there is no meaning of calling the super's `updateDisplay` function because it contains nothing.
The way it is at the moment, is actually a better solution than just resetting the values in the constructor, because you can call that `reset` function anytime without calling the constructor again which could contain other elements aswell. I would never use the constructor as a "resetter".

Comment: what do you mean that you don't update the display list? also thank you for taking the time to answer my question. i appreciate it.

Comment: If you change the value of "currentValue", the textfield's text will remain the same, because every time you change the currentValue's value, you have set the textfield's text to the new value. It will not update itself, you have to do it manually.